# VBA One Private Sub mouse move to many objects

Tags: excel, vba, userform, mousemove

i have a quick question:
It is possible to make one private sub with mousemove detection to all of my objects?

i have labels which names starts from J1 to J15 and textboxes which names starts from L1 to L15

```
Private Sub J1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If L1.Caption = "" Then J1.Caption = "" Else
J1.Caption = "OK"
J1.BackColor = &HC0FFC0
End Sub
```

And this is a code which i want to apply to all of my objects which have name J*

Comment: The `MouseMove` event is for each object, so, no, this is not possible. With some hacking you might pass the `Me` object to a shared function, but given what you do it will be of little added value.

Comment: The `If` statement is not needed as you set the caption unconditionally

Comment: You might look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592440/single-event-handler-for-multiple-combobox-controls-in-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single event handler for multiple ComboBox controls in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592440/single-event-handler-for-multiple-combobox-controls-in-vba)